# VBA: Use "Find" to get the row of a value / fixing object variable errors

Tags: excel, vba, function, find

I need to use the "find" function to get the row of a value, where that value is defined from another worksheet, but I keep getting object-variable not defined errors even when I try defining everything.

I was initially able to get the code below to work. (I paste the "test" version of the code that only uses a small range of 20 cells. The result is placed in cell "A1" to make sure it works correctly in testing.)

```
X = Range("D6").Value

Range("A1").Value = Range("D2:D20").Find(X).Row
```

But when I use this line in a large data set, I keep getting error 91 ("Object variable or With block variable not set").

So instead, I try code that defines everything more explicitly, but for the life of me, I can't get this code to work even on the small test set. (I also include a few lines that I've tried but that also produce errors.)

```
 Sub Test3()

    Sheets("2017").Select
    Dim X As Long
    X = Range("D6").Value

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("2017")

    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Dim FindRow As Range
    Set SearchRange = ws.Range("D2", ws.Range("D20").End(xlUp))
    Set FindRow = SearchRange.Find(X, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then ReturnRowNumber = FindRow.Row

    'Range("A1").Value = FindRow 'Running this row gives application-defined error 1004

    Dim i_2017 As Long
    i_2017 = FindRow.Rows(1)  'All of these rows give object variable not set error 91
    'i_2017 = FindRow
    'i_2017 = FindRow.Rows.Item(1)
    Range("A1").Value = i_2017 'Check that the sub returns 6

End Sub
```

If I try to return "FindRow" in cell "A1", I get error 1004 ("Application-defined or object-defined error")

If I try to store "FindRow" as another variable or use the "Item" property, I get error 91 ("Object variable or With block variable not set")

Comment: Just do `If Not FindRow Is Nothing Then msgbox findrow.row` and see what you get. It's a good idea to specify most Find parameters in case they are not set as expected.

Comment: You need to enclose all of your code related to your found variable inside the `If Not FindRow is Nothing Then` block. `FindRow` is returning nothing most likely which means every line that references `FindRow` will fail when nothing is found

Comment: I missed @urdearboy's point - perhaps you can post a screenshot as on the face of it the value should be found.

Comment: If FindRow is returning nothing, then that is a problem too since the search value is defined from the range that I'm searching, i.e. I defined X as the value in D6, then search D2:D20 to find the row of the value in D6.

Comment: Also, I would be happy to add a screen shot. I just have to figure out where the "attach file" button is first...

Comment: Why are you bothering to search column D for a value in D?

Comment: It is just test code to verify the formatting of the "find" function to that I can get the functionality I want in the bigger, "real" code, where I need to define a variable from a value in one spreadsheet and find the first row of the records associated with that identifier in another sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enclose all of your code that assumes `FindRow` has actually been **found** inside your `If Not FindRow is Nothing` statement.

```
Sub Test3()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("2017")
Dim Found As Range, ReturnRowNumber As Long

Set Found = ws.Range("D:D").Find (ws.Range("D6"), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlxWhole)

If Not Found Is Nothing Then
    'All code that assumes your value is found goes HERE
    ReturnRowNumber = Found.Row
    Range("A1").Value = Found
Else
    'All code that assumed your value is NOT found goes HERE
    MsgBox ws.Range("2017") & ": Not Found in Range"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I get the error "Method ‘Range’ of object ‘_Worksheet’ failed" for the line "Set Found = ws.Range..."

Comment: I'm getting the same error. I then tried changing "xlxWhole" to "xlWhole" and still got the same error.  I also really need to be able to use find with a variable name in the line so that in the final code, I can pass the value from a different sheet.  I'm just using "D6" for now to try to get a working example of using "find"

Comment: ok @LittleUrsus - try to copy the code one more time. I always use `Found` as my search variable and forgot to update some variable names as SJR pointed out

Comment: THANK YOU! The pasted code mixes "Found" and "FindRow." I also changed ws.Range"D6" to be X (after specifying X as Long) in order to use the code in the final version.  It works perfectly!